# Use variable in css class as class_name-parameter

Tags: css

Is there css syntax to make something like this?

```
.order-PARAMETER
{
    order: PARAMETER;
}
```

Comment: no, you need javascript to do this

Comment: you may take a look at preprocesssor such as less, sass , stylus. else in CSS level4 maybe there will be posibilities some day https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/

Comment: @paulie-d, really? paste here link to same question.

Answer (score 0):

Varaibles does not exist yet in CSS in a widely supported manner. There is an experimental variables feature in it but it lacks browser support (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)

If you would like to achieve that, either use JavaScript or a CSS extension language like Sass.